# How to return cross domain html in jsonp callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback, jsonp

I'm trying to build embedded widget for websites. This widget will be called from external websites using javascript.

When my widget's script added to a webpage below code runs:

```
var widget = {
    initialize : function(containerId)
    {
        (function($) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8002/callback.js';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
               $("#" + containerId).html(data);
            },
            error: function(e) {
               console.log(e.message);
            }
        });

        })(jQuery);
    }
}
```

this code is embedding my widget into given html container (div) And here is my callback:

```
jsonCallback(
    {"html": "<html><body>mahmut tuncer</body></html>" }
);
```

So, when i give hardcoded html as json, it works. Now, what i need to do is: Load another html file as json **before sending my callback back to requesting website**.

Comment: How to do that depends on the server side language you are using. Right now you seem to only have a static file. You need to run some server side code thats generates the response programmatically.

Comment: Can also consider CORS enabling your output so you don't need jsonp. Then you can send raw html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSONP and you're getting a cross-domain exception, that means the source you're trying to pull data from doesn't support JSONP. You might consider using node.js or something else to complete your task.

Comment: I am getting cross domain exception because my get request is runing on "requester" side, not at my source. I am aiming to change that.